# No audio header on my ASRock Motherboard

Tags: audio, motherboard

I am using an ASRock Rack E3C226D2I Motherboard, my front panel has an HD Audio Connector/AC' 97 connector. I originally thought that the motherboard must not support HD Audio so I searched in the manual and found absolutely nothing for audio in general. Am I missing something?

Manual for reference: http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/E3C226D2I.pdf

Comment: It looks like your motherboard doesn't have onboard audio. In order to have audio, you must install a sound card or a graphics card with audio capabilities.

Comment: I checked the [specifications of your MainBoard](https://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=E3C226D2I#Specifications) and couldn't find any reference to audio, too.

Comment: @milo8505 Comments are not for answers. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @zx485 Comments are not for answers. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: This board is server oriented, going by the supported OSes so it makes sense it has an obscure and minimal yet functional onboard graphics and no onboard audio. It has a typical PCIe x16 for graphics (or other) and nothing else. So, if you want audio just add a cheap USB external audio card or, if you want to add a proper graphics card, then that will provide HDMI audio as well. But obviously there won't be any audio header for analogue audio as you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the specifications of your MainBoard *ASRock Rack E3C226D2I* and [its specifications](https://www.asrockrack.com/general/productdetail.asp?Model=E3C226D2I#Specifications) indicate that it doesn't have any audio capability.

So I guess you have to add an

- *Audio PCI(e) card* or
- *USB Sound Device* or
- *HDMI audio* via an added Graphics Card to the PCIe-x16 slot

to have some sound.

Comment: Please read my comment above. Feel free to add from it.

Comment: I did, so I added the second possibility.

Comment: There's a third that, for me, would make more sense. Because it has only one PCIe slot x16, for me, adding a proper graphics card, even the lowest end new or second hand newish, would be galaxies better than the onboard graphics - that will struggle even with modern Solitaire, it's mostly for text mode - and would add HDMI audio.

Comment: If you say so... :)